# Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to a wrapper class

Tags: apex, unit-test, map, object

I have a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> seeMap = (Map<String, Object>) instance;
system.assert(seeMap.get('fish') != null, true); // this assert passes
System.debug(seeMap.get('fish')); // Gives me /*
({
  active=Active,
  exe=({
    eId=14234,
    salesforce_id=00Te000000X5hm5EAB
  },
  {
    eId=234132,
    salesforce_id=00Te000000X5hm5EAB
  })
})
*/
// I wish to convert this to a wrapper class(which was used to generate this structure in first place) so that I can assert // the correct values are set for each variable. So I used:

List<TargetClass> seg = (List<TargetClass>)seeMap.get('fish');  
// this gave me - Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to  List<TargetClass> 

public class TargetClass{

    String active;
    List<Execute> exe;

    class Execute{
        String eId;
        String salesforce_id;
    }

}
```

How can I convert this result and assert that the values are set correctly,Like active=Active has been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've obtained this data structure via `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`, resulting in a multi-level data structure composed of Apex primitives and collections of primitives like `Map<String, Object>`.

Once you obtain that "untyped" (it's not actually untyped, since Apex values are always typed at some level, but it's in generic collections) data, you can't cast it to specific custom classes, because it's not an instance of those classes. You'd need to either

- deserialize directly into strongly-typed data structures, using `JSON.deserialize()`, with a top-level class that represents the entire message and appropriately nests your data classes.
- Write constructors for your data classes that accept untyped data and initialize new instances from their contents, e.g., `public TargetClass(Map<String, Object> inputData)`. Those constructors will have to cast the actual content to its real, primitive data types, and perform any checking and validation that you need.